# How to install PostgreSQL 9.1 on OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, postgresql

I downloaded PostgreSQL from the official website and ran the .dmg installer. After that I downloaded pgadmin3 and I am indeed able to connect to the database.

when I run 'psql' I get the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
```

After hours of googling I read about some $PATH issues, so I put this into my .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:$PATH
```

However, this doesn't solve the error above at all. After some more hours of googling I tried to run 'psql -l localhost -U postgres'. This gives another error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After some more googling I tried to edit /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf and replaced all occurrences of 'md5' with 'trust'.

Then I changed user to postgres and executed 'pg_ctl stop' and 'pg_ctl start', switched back to my own user and tried to connect again, no luck.

Here are some more infos:

```
[~]$ which psql
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/psql

ps aux | grep postgres
postgres       19022   0.0  0.0  2446096    484   ??  Ss   11:31PM   0:00.01 postgres: stats collector process   
postgres       19021   0.0  0.0  2486532   1776   ??  Ss   11:31PM   0:00.01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
postgres       19020   0.0  0.0  2486400    576   ??  Ss   11:31PM   0:00.03 postgres: wal writer process   
postgres       19019   0.0  0.0  2486400    820   ??  Ss   11:31PM   0:00.05 postgres: writer process   
postgres       19017   0.0  0.0  2446096    356   ??  Ss   11:31PM   0:00.01 postgres: logger process   
postgres       19015   0.0  0.1  2486400   8216 s001  S    11:31PM   0:00.17 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postgres

sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432
No file was found?!?
```

Update 1:
In /etc/sysctl.conf I added the values suggested by the installer's README:

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
kern.sysv.shmall=393216
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=32
kern.sysv.shmseg=8
kern.maxprocperuid=512
```

Before these settings, the installer quits with an error, afterwards the wizard appears and installs postgres (and again, using pgadmin3 works, so I assume that the database is running fine).

Comment: Have you looked at the server log output? Often on new OS X installations Postgres fails to start because of a shared memory limit, see http://willbryant.net/software/mac_os_x/postgres_initdb_fatal_shared_memory_error_on_leopard

Comment: Just checked the logs, there are just lots of server stop and start messages, no errors at all. I will edit my post and add a word about shared memory. I think I did what was requested by the installer's README.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `lsof` on the master process to all of this. In your case it's 19015 (shown with my PID):

```
> sudo lsof -p 286 | awk '$5 == "unix" && $NF ~ /\// { print $NF }' 
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

You can leave off the awk, but basically it's getting the UNIX socket on which postgres is listening.  From there, you can use the `-h` option to `psql` (but only include the directory).

```
> psql -h /tmp template1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
template1=# \q
```

If that doesn't work, you can check the `lsof` output to show you what TCP port it's actually listening on, and if it's not 5432, use the `-p` option to postgres

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! lsof showed me that PostgreSQL was indeed listening to port 5433 (why? I never changed the port?). I edited .../data/postgresql.conf and set the port back to 5432, then restarted the server and everything works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to connect to the database through **pgadmin3**, then your database is running.

(1) I'd verify by running **netstat -an | grep 5432** on the command line, as a paranoia check. You are in business i.e. you actually installed Postgresql if you get this below:

tcp4       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN
ffffff80133bfed8 stream      0      0 ffffff8013be8000                0                0                0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

(2) Speaking for myself, I found that just running **psql** gets me your **psql** error message. I had to run

**psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 [-d database] -U postgres**

to connect with the database. In other words, I had to explicitly specify IP and port. Since you were able to run **psql** and get a non-connect error message, the OS understands that psql is a command and you don't have a pathing issue.