# PostgreSQL & Lion - Paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-lion

Trying to get postgres to work with Lion. When I run rake:db create I get:

```
could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

There are a lot of SO topics on the same issue but none of solutions have worked for me. Here is what I have tried:

- Uninstalled & reinstalled the pg gem
- Installed postgres.app (when I am connected to the local server, pg is still not working)
- Updated paths file so that usr/local/bin is above usr/bin
- Changed permissions on var/pgsql_socket to read/write for everyone

What might be a hint is that when I run which psql the result is usr/bin/psql - I believe it is meant to be usr/local/bin/psql, but after editing my paths file directly, I'm not sure why it hasn't changed. Homebrew is also working completely fine for me (no paths issue there).

Any ideas?

EDIT - What's in my database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: hubbed_development
pool: 5
username: hubbed
password:
host: localhost

test:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: hubbed_test
pool: 5
username: hubbed
password:

production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: hubbed_production
pool: 5
username: hubbed
password:
```

EDIT - After running ps aux | grep postgres:

```
 666   0.0  0.0  2445588    540   ??  Ss    9:42am   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process      
 664   0.0  0.1  2445588   3604   ??  S     9:42am   0:00.02 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/postgres -D /Users/angsmith/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var -p5432
 681   0.0  0.0  2434892    540 s000  S+    9:43am   0:00.00 grep postgres
 670   0.0  0.0  2441868    396   ??  Ss    9:42am   0:00.00 postgres: stats collector process      
 669   0.0  0.0  2445720   1524   ??  Ss    9:42am   0:00.00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process      
 668   0.0  0.0  2445588    488   ??  Ss    9:42am   0:00.00 postgres: wal writer process      
 667   0.0  0.0  2445588    524   ??  Ss    9:42am   0:00.01 postgres: writer process
```

EDIT - saw that in postgress.app my username was 'postgres'. After updating my database.yml username to postgres and running bundle exec rake db:create:all, I am now getting the following error (different to before):

```
 rake aborted!
 dlopen(/Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
 Reason: image not found - /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
 /Users/angsmith/hubbedspree/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
 /Users/angsmith/hubbedspree/Rakefile:5:in `require'
 /Users/angsmith/hubbedspree/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
 /Users/angsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: What do you have in database.yml?

Comment: @girasquid - edited to include it.

Comment: and postgres is running? `ps aux | grep postgres`

Comment: @jstim added the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install PostgreSQL 9.1 on OSX Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354122/how-to-install-postgresql-9-1-on-osx-lion)

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion

Comment: What username are you logged in as when you run Postgres.app?

Comment: @girasquid - sorry, just checked this again by running psql \l - I am connected to the database 'angsmith' as user 'postgres'. Is that correct?? I thought postgres.app created a user as your mac username?

Comment: It does - try changing the username in your database.yml.

Comment: Should I update my database.yml file to have 'postgres' as the username?

Answer (score 4):

In my case reinstalling the pg gem fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The entries for `development` have the `host: localhost` line but it's missing for the `test` and `production` configurations.

It should be included in all configurations, if your 3 databases are on the same server.

Comment: I have added that - no dice.

Comment: Does it output the exact same error message than before? That doesn't look plausible once it no longer tries to connect to the Unix domain socket.